# Работа с числами

Tags: php, числа

Здравствуйте, мне нужен класс для работы с числами. Просто при делении у меня будет получаться не всегда целые числа, нужно чтобы был метод округления, и метод для операциями над нецелыми числами, допустим 231.3738277237 + 4822.3672676272819190, просто обычно пхп округляет до десятитысячных. Прошу не написать, а есть ли готовые решения ибо изобретать велосипед не очень охото.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдет [BC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

```
<?php
$num1=bcsqrt('2', 1000);
$num2=bcsqrt('3', 1000);
echo bcadd($num1,$num2,500);
```

[пример с BC](http://ideone.com/NzNUDY)